# Groupby arrays in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider a dataframe with numpy arrays as entries for lat/lon:

```py
   lat       lon           min              max 
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]        10               90
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]        80               120
[7, 8, 9] [4, 5, 6]        10               20
[7, 8, 9] [4, 5, 6]        30               40
```

How can I group the dataset by unique lat/lon combinations when the entries are numpy arrays? The goal is to check if min/max ranges intersect for unique lat/lon combinations and then combine them to a single row with new min/max. The result should look like this:

```py
   lat       lon           min              max  
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]        10               120
[7, 8, 9] [4, 5, 6]        10               20
[7, 8, 9] [4, 5, 6]        30               40
```

What I have tried so far is:

```py
grouped = sectors.groupby(['lat', 'lon'])
```

But I can not access the groups in grouped. The following will result in an Error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'):

```py
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

Comment: Try casting astype str:  `df.groupby([df['lat'].astype(str), df['lon'].astype(str)]).agg({'min': 'min', 'max': 'max'})`

Comment: could you look at your example once more. for last two lines you need two or one row ?

Comment: @Atendra - I need two rows, because min/max is from 10->20 in the second last row and 30->40 in the last row, that means that both ranges do not intersect.